# Trying to create custom django mange.py command, getting errors

Tags: python, django, django-manage.py

Just starting out with Django.
I am trying to create a custom manage.py called "average" whose function is to compute the average of each field from Review model and update it in the "AvgMarks" model.

The models are :

```
class AvgMarks(models.Model):
collegeId = models.ForeignKey(College)
overall = models.FloatField()
academics = models.FloatField()
sports = models.FloatField()

class Reviews(models.Model):
collegeId = models.ForeignKey(College)
dateAdded = models.DateField(default=timezone.now())
authorName = models.CharField(max_length=25)
authorEmail = models.EmailField(max_length=100)
authorYear = models.IntegerField()
authorCourse = models.CharField(max_length=50)
category = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=CATEGORIES)
marks = models.FloatField(default="1.00")
review = models.TextField()

def __str__(self):
    return self.authorName
```

The content of "average.py" for manage.py is:

```
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand, CommandError
from django.db.models import Avg
from college.models import AvgMarks, College
from reviews.models import Reviews

class Command(BaseCommand):
help = "Calculates and save the average for a particular field"

def handle(self, *args, **options):
    colleges = College.objects.all()
    for i in colleges:
        AvgMarks.objects.filter(collegeId=i).update(
            overall = Reviews.objects.filter(collegeId=i).aggregate(Avg('marks'))['marks__avg'],
            academics = Reviews.objects.filter(collegeId=i, category="Academics").aggregate(Avg('marks'))['marks__avg'],
            sports = Reviews.objects.filter(collegeId=i, category="Sports").aggregate(Avg('marks'))['marks__avg'],
        )

    self.stdout.write("Averages done!")
```

On running "python manage.py average" command in Windows Powershell, I am getting the following error: **django.db.utils.IntegrityError: college_avgmarks.overall may not be NULL**

How do I fix it? TIA

Answer (score 0):

Before doing the `AvgMarks.objects.filter().update()` do poor-mans debugging

```
print(Reviews.objects.filter(collegeId=i).aggregate(Avg('marks'))['marks__avg'])
```

you'll see that it can become `None` from time to time (`Avg` returns `None` if there's no data to process) and `overall` isn't allowed to be `None`/`NULL` in your model definition.

Have a condition around it:

```
overall = Reviews.objects.filter(collegeId=i).aggregate(Avg('marks'))['marks__avg']
if overall is None:
    overall = 0

...update(overall=overall, ...)
```

You might also want to do this for the other `Avg`s

Comment: Thanks! Instead of trying to averaging the overall, because sometimes it become None, I calculated the individual category averages and then took out their arithmetic mean to compute overall average.